# Qt rubberband not being drawn

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to implement a rubberband. Here is my code.

```
void TOTMain::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QPoint origin = event->pos();
    _selectionSquare = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    _selectionSquare->setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize()));
    _selectionSquare->raise();
    _selectionSquare->show();
}

void TOTMain::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint origin = event->pos();
    _selectionSquare->setGeometry(QRect(origin, event->pos()).normalized());
}

void TOTMain::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    _selectionSquare->hide();
    // determine selection, for example using QRect::intersects()
    // and QRect::contains().
}
```

The issue is that the band is not being drawn. I confirm it is being constructed and persists through the dragging, but no rendering.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: on the chartview, you would setRubberband. void QChartView::setRubberBand(const QChartView::RubberBands &rubberBand)

Comment: Check your mouseMoveEvent: You set the rubberband's geometry to an empty rectangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your `mouseMoveEvent` implementation...

```
void TOTMain::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint origin = event->pos();
    _selectionSquare->setGeometry(QRect(origin, event->pos()).normalized());
}
```

You're setting the geometry of the rubber band to `QRect(origin, event->pos())`, but you've previously set `origin = event->pos()` so the top-left and bottom-right corners of the rectangle are the same.

Make `origin` a member variable variable of your class (untested)...

```
class TOTMain: public QWidget {
public:
protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        _origin = event->pos();
        _selectionSquare = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
        _selectionSquare->setGeometry(QRect(_origin, QSize()));
        _selectionSquare->raise();
        _selectionSquare->setStyleSheet("{ background-color : red; }");
        _selectionSquare->show();
    }
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        _selectionSquare->setGeometry(QRect(_origin, event->pos()).normalized());
    }
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        _selectionSquare->hide();
        // determine selection, for example using QRect::intersects()
        // and QRect::contains().
    }
private:
    QPoint       _origin;
    QRubberBand *_selectionSquare = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: You could probably use the rubber band's `pos()` instead of a member variable for the origin

Comment: @king_nak Possibly.  The only issue is that `pos()` always returns the position of the top-left corner whereas `_origin` as set/used in the code shown might actually represent any corner of the rubber band's geometry depending on how 'erratic' the user is with the mouse.  So it probably could be done but the code might become very terse.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP :-)

Comment: @GM yes, you're right... Didn't think about that ;)